# I would like for the spacing between my horizontal scrolling images to be exactly the same, how to achieve?

Tags: html, css, image, spacing

My CSS:

```
#container {
position: center;
margin-top: 80px;
z-index: 950;
{block:IfGridTheme}margin-left: 430px;{/block:IfGridTheme}
{block:IfNotGridTheme}margin-left: 435px;{/block:IfNotGridTheme}
}

.entry {
position: justify;
font-size: 12px;
color: {color:Body Text}; 
font-family: roboto condensed; 
letter-spacing: 1px; 
{block:PermalinkPage}width: 1000px;
margin-top: 15px;{/block:PermalinkPage}
word-wrap: break-word;
margin-top: 45px;
}

#container1 { 
white-space: nowrap; 
border: none; 
width: 100%;
margin-left: auto; 
margin-right: auto;
} 

#container1 > div { 
background: none; 
width: 100%; 
height: 100%; 
display: inline-block;
padding: 1% 5%; 
margin-right: 176px; 
}

.stretch {
width: 100%;
display: inline-block;
font-size: 0;
line-height: 0
}
```

and my HTML for a certain type of page:

```
<div id="container1">
<div>
<div class="picture_holder" style="width: 1080px;">
<div class="picture" style="width: 1080px;"><img alt="LINKTOFIRSTIMAGE" height="575" src="LINKTOFIRSTIMAGE" />
<div class="captioning">
<div class="caption"><em>CAPTION</em></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div>
<div class="picture_holder" style="width: 1080px;">
<div class="picture" style="width: 1080px;"><img alt="SECONDIMAGELINKANDSOFORTH" height="575" src="SECONDIMAGELINKANDSOFORTH" />
<div class="captioning">
<div class="caption"></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

On a given page with a sequence of images that are exactly the same height, width, and overall aspect ratio, the spacing between them is exactly the same (though a lot wider than I would like) like in `1)` of this drawing:

[image]

... but in a sequence of images that have the same height but wildly varying widths, the spacing is pretty off like in `2)`.

I personally don't want either. How do I change my code so that, for both these types of pages and however many more pages I plan to create, that the spacing between every *image* is exactly the same amount of pixels across the whole board of the site? Is there an imaginary box around these images causing the issue?

edit: I should also state that I am using the HTML function on a website, Tumblr.com, so certain properties like `flex` never seem available.

edit2: `display: grid;` and similar don't appear available either. This is also at the top of the code if that helps:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

Thank you for the info so far.

Comment: Your implementation is wrong. Make use of css flex and you're done.

Comment: How so? I tested using `display: flex;` under each element but the main problem seemed to be that the website I'm using doesn't seem to recognise "flex", as in it doesn't highlight as a certain color when I type it in like the rest. Same with `flex-wrap` and `flex-grow` and the others. @RichardPariath

Comment: Flex is supposed to be used in the container, not on individual element. I've written a short code as answer. maybe that can help

Answer (score 0):

Your html structure:

```
<div id="parent_container">
          <div id="card_1" class="card_properties">
            <h3>Title to image 1</h3>
            <img style="background:red">
            <caption>Card 1 caption</caption>
          </div>
          <div id="card_2" class="card_properties">
              <h3>Title to image 1</h3>
               <img style="background:violet">
            <caption>Card 2 caption</caption>
          </div>
          <div id="card_3" class="card_properties">
              <h3>Title to image 1</h3>
              <img style="background:seagreen">
            <caption>Card 3 caption</caption>
          </div>
          <div id="card_4" class="card_properties">
              <h3>Title to image 1</h3>
            <img style="background:skyblue">
            <caption>Card 4 caption</caption>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Your CSS structure:

```
  #parent_container <=== setting up flex for container
  {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;  <=== makes sure if the cards are many then they go on next line
    justify-content: space-evenly;  <=== makes sure there is equal space
  }
  .card_properties
  {
    border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.16), 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.23);
    border-radius: 14px;
    width:20vw;
    height:200px;
    padding:1em;
  }

  img  <=== written this additional because I didn't have time to find image
  {
   width: 100%;
   height: 120px;
   border-radius: 14px
  }
```

[Working codepen example](https://codepen.io/richardpariath3/pen/ZqRRQx)

Comment: thanks for the help! However, all `flex` properties don't highlight or appear to work whenever I type them, and I'm unclear on how to use the code for images and cards to expand for a different width and still remain on the same line. Is there anything else closely similar to flex?

Comment: if `flex` properties are not highlighting then it might have something to do with the IDE you are using. The preferences might not be set to CSS3. `Flex` automatically adjusts to the width change and in case you want to keep things in the same line you can use `flex-wrap:no-wrap` to keep it on the same line. Another Replacement would be to use CSS-Grids. Further reference on [Grids](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/) and [Flex](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox). Have attached working codepen in my answer.

Comment: The references make sense and it seems like this would be a solution but I'm still having trouble with the highlighting. I could not find anything on Google that referenced both "IDE" or "CSS3" and Tumblr's editor. I noticed something at the top of the overall code (I edited into the OP) that referenced `xhtml1` and I tried replacing it with the DTD link for, a newer html which didn't do anything? `grid`, `flex`, `fit-content` etc. all don't highlight; how do I change preferences like you said?